# Django FileField uploads a "None" File to the directory?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Classworks Model and in it I have added FileField to upload files in the media root, and I have tried to add a classwork using the admin, but when I checked the directory it said None!!! can someone explain why did this happen?? How can I upload it correctly and if it is uploaded correctly how can it be retrieved ?? here is the model :

```
def classwork_add_file(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    return f'uploads/{instance.Type}/{instance.Teacher}/{instance.Class}/{instance.questionNumber}/'


class ClassWorks(models.Model):
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="ClassWorks")
    Class = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Teacher = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    questionNumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Definition = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    File1 = models.FileField(upload_to=classwork_add_file, null=True, blank=True)
    File2 = models.FileField(upload_to=classwork_add_file, null=True, blank=True)
    File3 = models.FileField(upload_to=classwork_add_file, null=True, blank=True)
    File4 = models.FileField(upload_to=classwork_add_file, null=True, blank=True)
    File5 = models.FileField(upload_to=classwork_add_file, null=True, blank=True)
    DateAdded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    DateOfSubmission = models.DateTimeField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.Teacher is None:
            self.Teacher = self.Class.Teacher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upload_to` attribute value must be a function that returns the full path to file, including file name, not just the directory you want to save file in.
So you should change your **`classwork_add_file`** function:

```py
def classwork_add_file(instance, filename, *args, **kwargs):
    return f'uploads/{instance.Type}/{instance.Teacher}/{instance.Class}/{instance.questionNumber}/{filename}'
```

Also through this function you can change `filename` and save file with your desire name.

Comment: No! filename is automatically passed to "classwork_add_file" function by django when a file uploaded. You shouldn't import it. Just add it as parameter of function.